# Rails Action Mailerで送信した人と管理者の両方にメールを送る方法

Tags: ruby-on-rails

お問い合わせを受け付けた時にお問い合わせをした人とシステム運営者の両方に自動で受領メールを送付したいです。どのようにしたら送信できるでしょうか？

お問い合わせした人に送るメール文言とシステム運営者に送る文言は異なります。

**ユーザに送信**

```
class InquiryMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "maimai@gmail.com"


  def received_email(inquiry)
    @inquiry = inquiry
    mail to: "maimai@gmail.com", subject: "webサイトからお問い合わせがありました。"
  end


  def thanks_email(inquiry)
    @inquiry = inquiry
    mail to: inquiry.email, subject: "【maimai】お問い合わせを受け付けました"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

received_email メソッドはお問い合わせした人（ユーザ）宛てですよね？
そのメソッドとは別に「システム運営者宛に送信するメソッド」を作成します。

後はメール送信のタイミングで上記2つのメソッドをコールすれば良いと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。なぜかできないとはまっていましたが、別の箇所の問題たと気付くことができました。キューを入れ直したらうまくいきました。

Comment: 私が回答した時はメソッドが1つしかなかったですが、編集されて2つになったようですね。別の問題だったようで・・・ともあれ解決したのなら良かったです。